# How to match two patterns with RegExp

Tags: regex, excel, vba, excel-2007

I have 50,000 names and addresses all in one cell and I want to extract each element into separate cells HOWEVER one particular area is causing a headache. Some of the address fields contain two numbers for the street address. For instance a cell might contain "Mr Smith 10 Rillington Place Exeter Devon" which is fine as my code splits the name street city and County. But some cells contain "Smith & Sons Ltd. 10 & 12 High Street Sutton Surrey.

I have tried `.Pattern = "(\d+|\D+|\[d+ & \d+])"` but that does the same as `.Pattern = "(\d+|\D+)"`

```
Sub SplitTextNum2()
    Dim r As Range, rC As Range
    Dim Match, Matches
    Dim matchCount As Integer
    Columns("E").SpecialCells (xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Range("E1", Range("E50").End(xlDown))


    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "(\d+|\D+)"
        .Global = True
        For Each rC In r
            Set Matches = .Execute(rC.Value)
            For matchCount = 1 To Matches.Count
                rC.Offset(, matchCount).Value = Matches(matchCount - 1)
            Next
        Next rC
    End With
End Sub
```

My VBA Macro splits out "10" "&" "12" into separate cells. What I want it to do in this circumstance is to keep "10 & 12" together in one cell. The code needs to also cater for the single street number. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use the same alternation but start with `\d+ & \d+`

You can omit the `\[` because that matches a literal `[` and that character will first be matched by `\D` which matches not a digit.

If you intention was to create a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) by not escaping the first square bracket, the pattern would be the same as `[d+ &]`.

But the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) would not get there because all the matches will be matched by either `\d` which matches a digit or `\D` which matches not a digit.

You might use:

```
(\d+ & \d+|\d+|\D+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tXwZrF/1)

Comment: The fourth bird Wow! Brilliant! Thank you. I have a lot to learn about Regex but the site you pointed me to will certainly help in the future and your explanation here was just great.